# Movie set in scotland or somewhere up north

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

I am trying to find the title of a film I watched a few years back but never caught the ending. It was set in Scotland or somewhere up north. One of the opening scenes is a young boy being woken up by a noise outside his window and his father comes in and they look outside the window. It is the police beating a man inside a small blue van.

Another scene in the film is the same young boy years later, with his friend and dog in the park, a gang of youths ask him to play with his football but he refuses, so they kick his dog. the same youths then rape his girlfriend, they are caught and sent to prison. the same young boy then purposely goes to the same prison to organize their murder.

Comment: Dunno the film, but it sounds like the sort of cheerful feel-good movie that you want to watch in the summer.

Comment: How long ago was "a few years back"? Can you remember any of the actors? Can you remember any of the dialogue? Can you describe the characters in any better detail (age, ethnicity)? Was he successful in his revenge plot?

Comment: Neds? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1560970/?ref_=nv_sr_2

Comment: Posted a match, but it's best to mention an approximate year of release in ID.

Answer (score 3):

You're describing the Scottish gangster film [The Wee Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wee_Man) from 2013.

> In 1990 Glasgow, Paul Ferris (Martin Compston) is incarcerated at Barlinnie Prison in Glasgow. In his cell, he reflects on his childhood.
>
> One night, **young Paul's father puts him to bed after he is awoken by an assault in a van outside.** [...] The next morning, while walking his dog, **Paul witnesses an armed robbery on a local off-license by the Banks brothers, infamous local hooligans of a crime family, who afterwards harass young Paul and murder his dog.**
>
> In his teenage years, Paul is making his way to a party, when his father spies him carrying a knife, and convinces him to drop it. Later, the Banks brothers crash the party, threatening Paul and wrecking the house. In a fit of rage, Paul goes back to retrieve the knife, and returns to the house to find **two of the Banks brothers sexually assaulting his girlfriend.** He stabs both of them (albeit not killing them) and flees to his older sister's house, where she berates him for the violence, as their older brother is serving life in prison for murder. [...]
>
> **In prison, Paul arranges for one of the Banks brothers also in prison to be killed**, and fights his associate and friend Bob in order to be both thrown into solitary as an alibi.

Paul rises in the ranks after being released. The film was based on a [true story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Ferris_(Scottish_writer)). Here's the trailer: